# Why does Visual Studio disable the media buttons?

Tags: visual-studio, itunes

I've got iTunes running and the media buttons on my computer work with it. I've installed mmkeys.dll which has been recommended for making iTunes work with media keys in the background and it works fine with all apps - firefox, thunderbird, MSN messenger, Open Office.

But when Visual Studio 2008 is in the foreground the buttons stop working. Can't hit pause when the phone rings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please my my answer below _(from ~5 years ago!)_ as the correct solution if this is what worked for you?

Answer (score 50):

This is probably due to Visual Studio running as an Administrator, and whatever software controls your keyboard media buttons OR the media player itself does not run as admin.

As I was answering this question I decided to try opening iTunes as an administrator, and that solved the problem for me.

To make a program always open in admin mode:

1. Right click the program and select 'Properties'.
2. Select the 'Compatibility' tab.
3. Under 'Privilege Level' at the bottom, check check box 'Run this program as an Administrator'.

After you run & close the program for the first time with these settings, make you you tell it that the program worked correctly so that it will keep these settings.

Comment: I had the same problem. I'm running VS as admin with a Microsoft keyboard with custom mapped media keys (back/forward keys mapped to prev/next track, web home key mapped to lock desktop.) VS ignored custom mapping. But, instead of setting Spotify to run as admin, I set ipoint.exe and itype.exe to run as admin and restarted them, and my custom mapped keys started working properly even when VS had focus.

Comment: Yep, this solution worked with Amazon music player as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that those keys arn't mapped to some action in Visual Studio? A lot of the "media buttons" that I have seen really do key combos so Play might be Ctrl + Alt + P (I don't know any specific key values I'm just recalling the generic pattern I remember). You should be able to check this by going into Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. Select the "Press Shortcut Keys" text box then hit one of your media buttons. You will see a command become visible in the drop down below this text box showing what command it mapped to that combination.

Comment: Hi Jamone. Thanks but I tried that already and it doesn't seem to be the case. The text box is resolutely blank. Weird stuff.